# Clearing specific rows using RODBC

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

I would like to use the **RODBC package** to partially overwrite a Microsoft Access table with a data frame. Rather than overwriting the entire table, I am looking for a way in which to remove only specific rows from that table -- and then to append my data frame to its end.

My method for appending the frame is pretty straightforward. I would use the following function:

```
sqlSave(ch, df, tablename = "accessTable", rownames = F, append = T)
```

The challenge is finding a function that will allow me to clear specific row numbers from the Access table ahead of time. The *sqlDrop* and *sqlClear* functions do not seem to get me there, since they will either delete or clear the entire table as a whole.

Any recommendation to achieve this task would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does your dataframe have same exact number of columns as Access table?

Comment: Yes, the data frame has the exact same structure as the Access table. The majority of the frame basically consists of newer time-series data, but there are some overlapping entries too. Hence the attempt to remove these redundant records from the original table before appending. I am currently looking into the *sqlQuery* function in the RODBC package for potential solutions ...

Comment: FYI, these overlapping entries potentially contain updated results. That is why I want to keep the data frame versions, and remove the Access table versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, consider using `sqlQuery` to subset your Access table of the rows you want to keep, then `rbind` with current dataframe and finally `sqlSave`, purposely overwriting original Access table with `append = FALSE`.

```
# IMPORT QUERY RESULTS INTO DATAFRAME
keeprows <- sqlQuery(ch, "SELECT * FROM [accesstable] WHERE timedata >= somevalue")

# CONCATENATE df to END
finaldata <- rbind(keeprows, df)

# OVERWRITE ORIGINAL ACCESS TABLE
sqlSave(ch, finaldata, tablename = "accessTable", rownames = FALSE, append = FALSE)
```

Of course you can also do the counter, deleting rows from table per specified logic and then appending (NOT overwriting) with `sqlSave`:

```
# ACTION QUERY TO RUN IN DATABASE
sqlQuery(ch, "DELETE FROM [accesstable] WHERE timedata <= somevalue")

# APPEND TO ACCESS TABLE
sqlSave(ch, df, tablename = "accessTable", rownames = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

The key is finding the SQL logic that specifies the rows you intend to keep.

Comment: Thank you, Parfait. The second script seems to be my solution! I had considered the first option, but I wanted to avoid importing the table (since it is quite large). I will test the code soon ...

Comment: Just to follow up: This approach worked perfectly. Thanks again.